# AppleScript - Changing message status field of selected mail in Outlook

Tags: applescript, ms-office

Is there anyway to change MessageStatus column of outlook mail item? [image]

Outlook grid view provides different fields for mail item. One field is message status which indicates message is read/unread or important etc. Is there anyway to modify that field value? Can we show a custom icon for a specific mail?

Comment: Please add some more details about what you want to accomplish and what you have tried so far (even if it didn't work).

Comment: Outlook grid view provides different fields for mail item. One field is message status which indicates message is read/unread or important etc. Is there anyway to modify that field value? Can we show a custom icon for a specific mail?

please find the screenshot

Comment: @wlan I tend to use flags

Comment: It still might help to show what kind of research you already did on this.

Comment: @wlan I tend to use flags – ankiiiiiii 10 hours ago
What flags? I want to show a custom icon on one of the fields - message status or attachments field. is it possible on mac?

Comment: @wlan please use @ for pinging me. I meant that I dont use outlook, but as you can see in the rightmost corner, there is a flag feature. I use that for marking messages in different categories.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii; how do i mark it using AppleScript?